# Ruby No such file or directory @ dir_initialize even when the directory exist

Tags: ruby

**I have :**

```
ruby -v
=>ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

puts arg_provide
=>/home/user/Bureau/Clips graver

input_file_or_directory = Shellwords.shellescape(arg_provide).to_s

puts input_file_or_directory
=>/home/user/Bureau/Clips\ graver
```

**When i do**

```
Dir.foreach("/home/user/Bureau/Clips\ graver") do |media|
=> IT'S WORKS FINE!
```

**But when i do**

```
Dir.foreach(input_file_or_directory) do |media|
=>Raise Uncaught exception: No such file or directory @ dir_initialize 
- /home/user/Bureau/Clips\ graver
```

**I can't figure it out 
Somebody help me please ?**

Comment: check for puts input_file_or_directory.class

Comment: Hello
puts input_file_or_directory.class give me
=>String

Comment: Try `Dir.foreach(arg_provide) do |media|` it worked for me.

Comment: @Nandu Kalidindi you righ it's works but why input_file_or_directory doesn't work?

Comment: Because if you print `input_file_or_directory` using `p input_file_or_directory` you can see a `//` double escape which is not being recognised by the Dir.foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Dir.foreach(arg_provideinput_file_or_directory)
```

with

```
Dir.foreach(arg_provide.to_s)
```

Comment: Hello, same result with Dir.foreach(input_file_or_directory.to_s)
Uncaught exception: No such file or directory @ dir_initialize 
- /home/user/Bureau/Clips\ graver

Comment: why you dont directly pass arg_provide in Dir.foreach(arg_provide.to_s)

Comment: yes Dir.foreach(arg_provide.to_s) works but why not wit input_file_or_directory. this is weird

Comment: Shellwords.shellescape(arg_provide).to_s gives double // which is not being recognised by the Dir.foreach

Comment: Hi @user7333505, I cant right now. This is a new account. Voting is still locked. But yes i got the answer. Thank you very much